# Multiple schema in Apollo Android

Tags: android, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, graphql-java

I am using Apollo Client in Android Project. I have 2 schema file and I have put them 2 different directories.

1. src/main/graphql/com/example/data/search/schema.json
2. src/main/graphql/com/example/data/user/schema.json

But when I build a project to generate code by Apollo It gives me an error:

> **`ApolloGraphQL: By default, only one schema.json file is supported.`**

and suggest me to use **multiple service**
Build output:

```
ApolloGraphQL: By default, only one schema.json file is supported. Please use multiple services instead: 

apollo {
  service("search") {
    sourceFolder = "/.../app/src/main/graphql/com/example/data/search" 
  }

  service("customer") {
    sourceFolder = "/.../app/src/main/graphql/com/example/data/customer" 
  } 
}
```

I have also added this to my `build.gradle`(app level) file but still shows the same build error.

Please suggest me how can I solve this error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My Problem was resolved with this configuration

```
apollo {
  // configure ApolloExtension here
  generateKotlinModels.set(false) // Generate Kotlin models for all services

  service("search") {
      sourceFolder.set("com/example/data/search")
      rootPackageName.set("com.example.data.search")
  }
  service("customer") {
      sourceFolder.set("com/example/data/customer")
      rootPackageName.set("com.example.data.customer")
  }

  onCompilationUnit {
      // Overwrite some options here for single CompilationUnit if needed
  }
}
```

Hope this may help others

Comment: Hello Abu I wanted to keep separate schemas on basis of build types(debug and prod) and that too dynamically. Could you help me out?

Comment: I didn't try that yet. One way could be use same `interface` for both `debug` and `prod` implementation.

Comment: Could you please elaborate